# Soldering lifted central pin of TO-252-5 package

Tags: voltage-regulator, soldering, routing

I found a very nice voltage regulator of ST (LD39300). But the LD39300PT-R has a package with a lifted central pin (TO-252-5, DPak (4 Leads + Tab), TO-252AD). 
Here is a photo:

[image]

I just want to do a routing of my PCB but I don't know how to solder the central ground pin.

With an extra cable?

Why is the central pin not manifactured like the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's interesting that the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00150604.pdf) doesn't seem to mention this, but it's pretty clear that the mounting tab is supposed to be used for the ground connection, not the truncated middle pin.

Answer (score 3):

While not explicitly stated in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00150604.pdf), Ground Pins, even floating stubs like pin 3 in the PPAK or pin 2 in the DPAK, are normally tied to the heatsink tab on the package. You need to mount the dpak on a heatsink, or to the copper on the pcb, and that should be connected with the ground plane for your PCB.

You can test this by using a multimeter in continuity mode, between the tab and the pin 3.

Comment: This package is designed so the tab is always soldered to copper on the PCB.